# Installing DIY Solar, I need help bringing the power into my home

Tags: solar

I'm going to disconnect my home from the grid (I will not be grid tied). I plan to remove all 240v appliances. My question is would I still need a split inverter 120v/240v to run the whole house?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're eliminating all 240v appliances?

Comment: Does the house have any **multi-wire branch circuits**?  Any red wires in the panel other than the 240V circuits you are removing?

Comment: @FreeMan OP is pulling the house off the utility grid, and running solar/battery solely. Large 240V appliances such as A/C, strip heat, water heater, range and dryer, are challenging to put on a battery solar system, owing to the large size of battery needed.  (although not so bad anymore given how solar panels and batteries are in price freefall).  So OP is asking "If I eliminate 240V appliances, do I even need a 240V inverter?"   Or to rephrase, "Can I reconfigure my service panel to be 120V only?"

Comment: Is there a reason you want to pass up on grid-tying, such as the utility not being willing to buy power from you on a reasonable basis?  What are you planning to use for *storage*?